# Deploying Docker image to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a spring boot app following this [tutorial](https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot/security-login-mysql-jsp/). Following the tutorial I managed to dockerize my app with the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

When I check for docker images afterwards I see the new image for the app. Now I want to deploy this app to AWS elastic beanstalk. When creating the environment with docker platform what do I need to upload for the application code? How do I upload my docker image to aws? I can't find a good tutorial on how to deploy a dockerized app/image to aws like this. I am new to docker so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update Oct 2020

**Docker-compose is now officially supported** by EB:

- [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Adds Support for Running Multi-Container Applications on AL2 based Docker Platform](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-elastic-beanstalk-support-running-multi-container-applications-al2-based-docker-platform/)

#### Original answer below

EB **does not support docker-compose**. To make your container (is it single, or multiple-conatiner setup?) you have to use either [single](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker.html) or [multi-container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html) EB platforms.

In both cases you have to translate your `docker-compose.yml` into [Dockerrun.aws.json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html#create_deploy_docker_ecs_dockerrun). The file has different form, depending on whether you are using single or multi-container setup.

> How do I upload my docker image to aws?

If its single EB setup, you can just provide your `Dockerfile` to EB and it will take care of everything for you. For multi-conainer EB, you can store your images in public repo such as dockerhub, or a private repo such as [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/).

To translate your `docker-compose.yml` file into `Dockerrun.aws.json`, you can try using [container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform) tool. It can be helpful, though you will most likely need to **manually** make further adjustments to the file generated.

Comment: Thanks! this has cleared up a lot for me! From my docker-compose.yml file (I updated my question to include the file) as far as I understand it is a single container setup. Am I right? Or are services something else than container? In the case of a single EB setup you say that I can just provide my Dockerfile to EB, how exactly do I do this? Do I need to do this in the EB cli?

Comment: @AlfieDanger Hi. No problem. Glad it was helpful :-) Yes, you can just use your Dockerfile. EB will build the image. And yes, you can use eb cli for that as well. Details are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#single-container-docker-configuration.dockerfile).

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. As of 2020-10-07, [Elastic Beanstalk **does** officially support multi-container setups using a docker-compose.yml file](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-elastic-beanstalk-support-running-multi-container-applications-al2-based-docker-platform/). (This just burned us on our last deploy since we were using docker-compose for local development testing but only the Dockerfile in production.)

Comment: @beporter Thanks for letting me know. I will update the answer.